# Unable to send mail with Rails, STARTTLS not recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails to develop a webapp. I want it so that when an user signs up an unique hash is sent to their e-mail which they will have to enter on the website to validate their account.

I get an error when I try to deliver the e-mail.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "mail.XXX.com",
 :port                 => "25",
 :user_name            => 'test@XXX.com',
 :password             => 'XXXXXX',
 :authentication       => :login,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :tls                  => false}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

When I use these settings to try send an email I am greeted with this error:

[image: Error Message]

I am using this from my localhost, the login is correct aswell as the ports and the addresses.
Also no e-mail is getting sent. I am getting a similar error when trying to send an email trough thunderbird from the same address, it might be linked.

When sending an email from the webmail space it works.

I am using Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the same error when sending from thunderbird, you probably have something wrong with your `smtp` configuration.
Please let us know what is your email provider and the configuration your have used for `SMTP`. It should be under `config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb`.
You can also find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration).

Comment: The configuration is the on you see in the question. The e-mail provider is the 'default' email server that comes when purchasing hosting. I can only access it with cpanel.

Comment: well... the configuration is probably wrong, as you said that you can't access the email through thunderbird. In your Cpanel, under emails, try to find the option `configure email client`. So you will be able to find the correct configuration. You should be able to send and receive emails using thunderbird ou any other "outlook" before you start trying to configure your Rails application.